# parsing xml and html page with lxml and requests package in python

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, python-requests, lxml

I have been trying to parse xml and html page by using lxml and requests package in python. I using the following code for this purpose:

in python:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree
url = ""
req = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(req.content)
root = tree.xpath('')
for item in root:
     print(item.text)
```

This code works fine but for some web pages can't show their contents properly and need to set encoding utf-8 but i don't know how i can add set encoding in this code

Answer (score 0):

`requests` automatically decodes content from the server.

**Important to understand:**

`r.content` - contains not yet decoded response content

`r.encoding` - contains information about response content encoding

`r.text` - according to the [official doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content ) it is already decoded version of `r.content`

Following the unicode standard, I get used to `r.text` but you still can decode your content manually using

```
r.content.decode(r.encoding)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i try tree = html.fromstring(req.text) but Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported by lxml and don't work

Comment: works for me. I tried both ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 pages. which lxml version do you use? could you provide a link where you request page?

Comment: url = "http://asretebar.com/rss/feed/?c=1&m=6"
req = requests.get(url)
#req.encoding = "utf-8"
#req.content.decode(req.encoding)
tree = html.fromstring(req.text)
root = tree.xpath('channel/item/title')
for item in root:
    print(item.text)

Comment: Rustem K Thank you very much gave the answer to my question